# file_put_contents записывает кракозябры

Tags: php, кодировка

Файл с кодировкой utf8, создаю переменую

```
$str = 'ааыв';
file_put_contents('ile.txt', $str , FILE_APPEND);
```

И в файл записывает подобное:

```
Р°Р°С‹РІ
```

Как записывать в файл что бы рсские были символы?..

```
mb_detect_encoding($str );// UTF-8
```

Через echo выводит строку правильно, русскими символами на страничке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = 'ааыв';
file_put_contents('ile.txt', iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $str) , FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 2):

вот попробуй самое простое решение: в самый верх допиши это:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Нет, это что бы отображалось на сайте в какой кодировке, ответ ниже,  все равно спасибо.

Comment: @user190134 прошу прощения, проглядел. спасибо за оценку!